# Multiple (dev) sites running locally; session seemingly randomly times out

Tags: control-panel, session

I've got multiple sites running on XAMPP (I'm on Windows 10). Each has its own domain (eg. `dev.example.local`, `dev.otherexample.local`, etc).

When I try to have more than one site CP page open in the same browser, I tend to randomly encounter session timeout modal windows.

Craft 2 had the `overridePhpSessionLocation` which I suspect might help, but I can't find the equivalent in Craft 3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would `phpSessionName` help? Docs - https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#phpsessionname

Comment: I don't see how, unfortunately. Craft's session cookies appear to be properly scoped to the domain & subdomain.

Comment: The replacement for `overridePhpSessionLocation` is to set https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php directly in your php.ini file.

Comment: So turns out my PHP sessions are getting saved to `c:\xampp\tmp\`. It looks like they're all there, valid and writable and whatnot. No clue why I get logged-out of the Craft backend locally so much.